# Vector data from a file

Tags: python, data-structures, file-io

I am just starting out with Python.  I have some fortran and some Matlab skills, but I am by no means a coder.  I need to post-process some output files.

I can't figure out how to read each value into the respective variable.  The data looks something like this:

> h5097600N1      2348.13       2348.35     -0.2219        20.0      -4.438
>    h5443200N1      2348.12       2348.36     -0.2326        20.0      -4.651
>    h8467200N2      2348.11       2348.39     -0.2813        20.0      -5.627
>   ...

In my limited Matlab notation, I would like to assign the following variables of the form tN1(i,j) something like this:

```
tN1(1,1)=5097600; tN1(1,2)=5443200; tN2(1,3)=8467200; #time between 'h' and 'N#'
hmN1(1,1)=2348.13; hmN1(1,2)=2348.12; hmN2(1,3)=2348.11; #value in 2nd column
hsN1(1,1)=2348.35; hsN1(1,2)=2348.36; hsN2(1,3)=2348.39; #value in 3rd column
```

I will have about 30 sets, or tN1(1:30,1:j); hmN1(1:30,1:j);hsN1(1:30,1:j)

I know it may not seem like it, but I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now.  I am trying to learn this on my own and it seems I am missing something fundamental in my understanding of python.

Comment: how is you data loaded in? is it loaded into a list?

Comment: suggest reading up on the Pandas library..

Comment: I'm using file=open("path/filename") and then line=file.readline() to get each line from the file.  I have been able to parse out some key data using conditionals, but I'm stuck on getting these values into the appropriate matrix form.  Eventually I will need to plot(tN1(1,:),hmN1(1,:)), etc.

Comment: How is the data stored? Which variable tell you which set of data you are working on? Is the line number important? My solution gives you `t[2][0] == 8467200`, not `t[2][2] == 8467200`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple script which does what you asks. It creates three dictionaries, `t, hm` and `hs`. These will have keys as the N values.

```
import csv
import re


path = 'vector_data.txt'

# Using the <with func as obj> syntax handles the closing of the file for you.
with open(path) as in_file:
    # Use the csv package to read csv files
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=' ')
    # Create empty dictionaries to store the values
    t = dict()
    hm = dict()
    hs = dict()
    # Iterate over all rows
    for row in csv_reader:
        # Get the <n> and <t_i>  values by using regular expressions, only
        # save the integer part (hence [1:] and [1:-1])
        n = int(re.findall('N[0-9]+', row[0])[0][1:])
        t_i = int(re.findall('h.+N', row[0])[0][1:-1])

        # Cast the other values to float
        hm_i = float(row[1])
        hs_i = float(row[2])

        # Try to append the values to an existing list in the dictionaries.
        # If that fails, new lists is added to the dictionaries.
        try:
            t[n].append(t_i)
            hm[n].append(hm_i)
            hs[n].append(hs_i)
        except KeyError:
            t[n] = [t_i]
            hm[n] = [hm_i]
            hs[n] = [hs_i]
```

Output:

```
>> t
{1: [5097600, 5443200], 2: [8467200]}
>> hm
{1: [2348.13, 2348.12], 2: [2348.11]}
>> hn
{1: [2348.35, 2348.36], 2: [2348.39]}
```

(remember that Python uses zero-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments.  Suggested readings led to other things which helped.  Here is what I came up with:

```
if len(line) >= 45:
    if line[0:45] == " FIT OF SIMULATED EQUIVALENTS TO OBSERVATIONS": #! indicates data to follow, after 4 lines of junk text
         for i in range (0,4):
             junk = file.readline()
         for i in range (0,int(nobs)):
             line = file.readline()
             sline = line.split()
             obsname.append(sline[0])
             hm.append(sline[1])
             hs.append(sline[2])
```